# Access QueryString parameters in Angular when redirected from an ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, webforms

I am having an ASP.NET WebForms application in which I am trying to integrate Angular.

To keep it simple, I have a **Login.aspx** and **Dashboard.aspx**.

Login.aspx has a 'Login' button and on its 'click' event handler i'm redirecting to the Dashboard.aspx with below line of code:

```
Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx?auth-token=abcd1234");
```

I have integrate Angular in the Dashboard.aspx page and the markup for it is as below:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/NgDashboard/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="styles-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="styles-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
</body>
```

Now when I run the asp.net application's Login.aspx, I have the URL as:

```
https://localhost:44303/Login.aspx
```

And when I click on 'Login', I want the URL to be as:

```
https://localhost:44303/Dashboard.aspx?auth-token=abcd1234
```

To prevent Angular from changing the URL I have made the below change to the AppRoutingModule (as per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53196790/how-to-disable-url-changes-with-angular-routing)):

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      initialNavigation: false
    })
```

I have not added any other routes in my angular application. So I'm trying to read the query string parameter 'auth-token' inside the AppComponent with the below code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.queryStringAuthToken = params["auth-token"];
    });
```

Now, even though I'm able to get the url as expected, the angular app is not reading able to read the query string parameter.

So how can I read the query string parameters from Angular when I redirect from one aspx page to a second aspx page which has the angular app inside it?